# How to reference the left-most cell of a row, in conditional formatting?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I'd like reference the left-most cell of a row, to determine if should be shaded or not. If the value in the left-most cell of a row matches the value in a specific (absolute) cell reference, then the target cell should be shaded.

Basically, I have target weight (say 50 Kilos) that's in a specific cell - say $A$1

Then, if the left-most cell of any other cell in the sheet has the value of $A$1, I'd like it to be shaded.

Not sure how to write this.

EDIT - here's a sample of what I'd like to do. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a7NvHSIdKbDp4cZ8FHbBaj7LzMSS04i9NVnBw0UaNwY/edit?usp=sharing

You will need to save a copy in order to edit it. Functionally, this does what I want (change the shading for the appropriate row, depending on what you put in cell A3), but I did it in a really complicated way.
Just thinking there must be a better way...

Comment: this is kinda confusing... "the left-most cell" is always column A (if you are not from right-to-left country) can you share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output?

Comment: I added a sheet and some notes, hope it helps clarify. I may be missing something really obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
=$A6=$A$3
```

[image]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19CiuQ0gEzEG7l5qER1tc7rm0PJIBubFfT6AusOkJeZk/copy)